# Compile C# as CGI

Tags: c#, linux, apache, cgi, lamp

How do you compile a C# program as CGI to run in the cgi-bin of a LAMP/Linux/Apache server?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Are you using Mono?

Comment: libsecondlife @ http://lib.openmetaverse.org/wiki/Main_Page is one C# based API, which I'd like to run on my LAMP dedicated server. i've been able to compile a couple of C++ based programs into cgi to run on my LAMP server, but not sure how to do this for .NET C#

Answer (score 1):

Maybe, you could use a very simple wrapper script, e.g., with bash, that itself executes your C# program with mono in the normal way. *e.g.*:

```
#!/usr/bin bash

/usr/bin/opt/mono myprogram.exe $@
```

(Of course, just using Apache with [mod_mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Mod_mono) is a much better solution, if you can.)

Answer (score 1):

Nothing special is required - just compile the application as normal with Mono's gmcs compiler.

For more information on integration, check out these two links:

http://www.mono-project.com/ASP.NET

and this one for CGI specifically:

http://www.mono-project.com/CGI

Comment: I agree with Stewart that Apache with mod_mono is a much better solution than CGI or FASTCGI.

Comment: this looks like it's the solution. will try this tomorrow, but just wondering has anyone tried compiling C#/.NET into CGI?

Comment: this seems to work for some basic apps, but not all libraries seem encapsulated for more complex apps (still text-based though)..

Answer (score 1):

You usually compile C programs using the compiler on the server, often the gnu compiler.
If this is the complier you are using then;

```
gcc -o <name_of_output_file>.cgi <name_of_source_file>
```

Whatever you name the file you need to give it the extension **.cgi**
 All You have to do then is to move it to the cgi-bin folder, remember to set the permissions of the program, usually for cgi stuff you use 755;

```
chmod 755 <name_of_file>
```

This is how I do it for C, C# I imagine is the same.

Comment: don't forget to optimize with -O2!  ;))